# I'm using angularjs and I'm not able to redirect my pages from the home screen. I'm using ng-route module. Please review my code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my code for index.html. I'm not able to load login.html whenever I'm clicking on login button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="instagram">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compitable" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Instagram</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><i class="ion-images"></i> instagram</a>
      <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/login">Log in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
      <li><a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div ng-view=""></div>
<script src="Vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/satellizer.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers/home.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers/login.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers/signup.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers/detail.js"></script>
<script src="Controllers/navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my code for app.js. I got this issue for home page also it got resolved using ng-view.

```
angular.module('instagram', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages','satellizer']).
  config(function($routeProvider, $authProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
      })
      .when('/photo/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'Views/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise('/');

    $authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login';
    $authProvider.signupUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/signup';
    $authProvider.oauth2({
      name: 'instagram',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000',
      clientid: '48c078d56c5d4f4e9962e06443b4f156',
      requiredUrlParams:['scope'],
      scope: ['likes'],
      scopeDelimiter: '+',
      authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize'
    });

  });
```

The code looks alright to me.Please let me know what mistake I'm making.

Comment: I'm able to load home.html. But not login.html.

Comment: I don't believe you need the `#` in front of your urls it gets added by the router.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? And what does it display in the address bar after clicking on the login link?

Comment: Why isn't this on the code review site? http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Check here i have made a working sample without injecting **`ngMessages`** and  **`satellizer`**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="nav">
          <a href="#login" class="button">Login</a></a>
          <a href="#signup" class="button">Signup</a>
          <a ng-click="logout()" href=""></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LQw01BbrLa3yJWjo301G?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's still not working. kindly provide other solution if possible.

Comment: did you check the sample ?

Comment: yes.sample is working. but when I'm doing same in my app it's not working.

Comment: @DharakShah Create a plunker for your issue and post here